# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in spite of using CLASSPATH environment variable

Tags: java, environment-variables, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to connect to mysql database using java on windows7. In spite of adding the complete url of jdbcdriver jar file in CLASSPATH, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
is thrown. Could anyone tell me what i am missing here? It works if I add the jar file in project library but I want to do it by CLASSPATH itself.
My classpath looks like this-
C:\jython2.5.1\javalib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar

I want to make it clear that this is not the actual project i am working on. I am actually using Django with Jython, which requires the JDBC driver to access the database. That is the reason why I have to do it using CLASSPATH only.

Comment: with what are you building your project?

Comment: ...and if you're doing this from a command prompt, can you also show the exact command-line you're using?

Comment: i am using netbeans ide. Actually i was getting this error while using  django with jython, so i thought i should try connecting to mysql database from plain java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is **only** used by the `java.exe` command and even then only when used *without* any of the `-cp`, `-classpath`, `-jar` arguments. It is **ignored** by IDEs like Eclipse, Netbeans and IDEA.

That environment variable is in real world also considered a poor practice since it breaks portability. I.e. program X will run successfully while program Y won't run without altering the `CLASSPATH`. It's only "useful" for <s>Sun</s> Oracle to prevent that starters get tired of typing the same classpath again and again in the `-cp` or `-classpath` arguments when following Java tutorials. In real world, batch/shell files are preferred where just the entire command with `-cp`/`-classpath` argument is specified.

In your case you're using an IDE. The classpath is there called the "Build Path". In plain Java projects, it represents *both* the compiletime and runtime classpath. You can configure it in the project's properties. You can add a complete folder, you can add individual/external JAR files, you can link projects, etcetera. Make use of it. Forget about using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. It was a mistake by <s>Sun</s> Oracle. They thought to convince starters, but it ended up to be only more confusing to starters as they incorrectly interpret that environment variable as **the** classpath.

#### See also:

- [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/when-and-where-to-add-jar-files-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnot/)

Comment: Thanx for you reply, Actually my project is on django and jython. jython runs on jvm and it needs jdbc drivers to access db. I dnt know of any other way to include a jar file.

Comment: The detailed answer depends on the runtime environment. At least, you can use `sys.path` environment variable (which is by the way similar to `CLASSPATH` and thus also unportable), or the command argument `-Dpython.path`.

Answer (score 12):

What finally helped me out was to copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar to \jre\lib and to \jre\lib\ext both(!) even though I did all the classpathing circus Java offers :) Environment was pure notepad/commandline though.

Comment: Here is a link as of today, you can download the platform independent one from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/#downloads

Comment: Complete path is yout actual java platform. For example in Linux amd64 can be /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/

Answer (score 9):

What worked with me using Netbeans was:
Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize.
Under Libraries > Add Library. Added MySQL JDBC Driver (I assume it appeared in list because I copied the jar file to the jre\lib\ext folder.
And it worked seamlessly.

I tried setting classpath but that did not work. I am using Netbeans 7.0

Comment: Thank god for this answer. I've been fighting with this problem for the last 2 1/2 hours, and you fixed it for me.

Comment: OMG you're the best! Setting classpath didn't work for me either! I'm using eclipse but it's similar. So for those of you that are using eclipse: right click on the project -> Run Configuration -> Classpath -> add it there.

Comment: Thanks @DaoLam that worked for me. Up Vote for you! and you too, nandan

Answer (score 3):

simply do a right click on your project in "Netbeans" select properties then click on "libraries " then click on "add library..." button then select "MySQL JDBC Driver" and click on "add library" button then on "OK" button

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem before, but after ***I put/added mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar (Download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)) into the apache-tomcat-8.0.15\lib folder***, and then ran my project, it really did work.

**Note : Even after adding the jar file the error persists, then restart the Tomcat server and rerun you project again.**

Comment: Worked for me. Java newbie. added this .jar to eclipse buildpath. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Netbeans IDE
2. Right-click your Project.
3. Select Properties.
4. On the left-hand side click Libraries.
5. Under "Compile" tab - click Add Jar/Folder button.
6. Select Downloaded "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar" file ([Download Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) from dev.mysql.com)
7. Click OK
8. Run Again... Its work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven, add the dependency to `pom.xml` should solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Solved it! If you are using maven then just use this!

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans IDE just Check the properties of Project on which you working on,in properties window go to 'library' tag, in diolog box just add your mysql-connector-java-****.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in Netbeans.  Because I was using a tomcat connection pool as defined in context.xml I needed to add the jdbc jar to both the project (Properties->Libraries) and to the lib/ folder within my Tomcat server so it could be seen on startup.