# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb (Netbeans)

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, mariadb

I'm using the `mariadb-java-client-1.5.7.jar` connector for MariaDB, and it does not work.

Here's the connection code:

```
    public DataAccess() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
        this.host = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost/bluebank";
        this.user = "root";
        this.password = ""; 
        Class.forName(this.driver);
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.host, this.user, this.password);
    }
```

I get:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost/bluebank
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at DAO.DataAccess.<init>(DataAccess.java:31)
```

Apart from adding as an external jar to the libraries, I've added it as a driver to the databases in (Services) in Netbeans. Also, if I remove the `Class.forName()`, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: what DBMS you are using, MySql or what?

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020857/connect-to-mariadb-from-java-application-in-netbeans-on-linux-mageia

Comment: The answer given was right. I was missing the port. I don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: i'm the one who make this, i thought it is another problem, for that i tried to ask some questions before

Comment: "Does not work" does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the port number of your database :

```
this.host = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:port_number/bluebank";
```

Make sure that your db connector jar, exist in the your jar libraries: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/

You can learn more here :

[Connect to MariaDB from Java application in NetBeans on Linux (Mageia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020857/connect-to-mariadb-from-java-application-in-netbeans-on-linux-mageia)

Hope this can help you

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this is the actual cause, as the driver defaults to port 3306 when none is specified, see also [the documentation](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/documentation/use-mariadb-connector-j-driver.creole) which makes clear that port is optional

Comment: mmm, i don't know @MarkRotteveel i suggest this solution and in fact it worked with him, or maybe he has another port?

Comment: Maybe, or their was an unrelated problem (outdated files), and editing the config triggered a rebuild or something else that fixed the problem

Comment: ok @MarkRotteveel, so, you find my answer not useful, maybe the OP can share with us how this work with him :)

Comment: I can understand that to the OP it looks like this solved his problem (which is also why I didn't downvote or anything), but - ignoring the possibility of bugs in the MariaDB Connector/J - there is no way this can be what actually fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Had something similar today. Worked in Eclipse, did not with pure Java.

For me it was important to have

```
Class.forName ("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

to make it work everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

**replace mariadb in the url with mysql:**

I had this Problem myself: the solution was quite simple... MariaDB is basically still MySQL. In the Url you are using to connect to the Database (jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306) you can therefore just use jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 <- i just replaced mariadb with mysql. It is still running on a mariadb server but it works so dont change it ;)

Still i dont know why none of the other solutions have worked but at least it is a solution