# Can't connec to Mariadb from Java Netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I'm having a problem connecting my from Java in Netbeans with mariadb in localhost. I've been seeing some post like this [Connect to MariaDB from Java application in NetBeans on Linux (Mageia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020857/connect-to-mariadb-from-java-application-in-netbeans-on-linux-mageia) but doesn't work it's pretty similar so I don't know why this post can't help me.

```
public BD(String servidor, String database, String usuario, String password) throws SQLException{
    try {


        Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/ddsi";
        conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);

        System.out.println("Conexion a Base de Datos "+url+" . . . . .Ok");

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

As in the previous link I've tried everything. I also have mariadb library.
[image]

I checked skip-networking directive in /etc/my.cnf but it is already commented.

Comment: Well what happens? Do you get an error of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *sources* JAR in your classpath, that won't work. Get a regular JAR `mariadb-java-client.jar` and put it on the classpath. Better yet use a dependency management tool like gradle or Maven.