# Error in My java oracle connectivity ... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, oracle

I just got some errors in my Java  oracle connectivity. Could anyone please help me with this? I have enclosed the code below. I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver..
```

this is the code

```
package md5IntegrityCheck;    
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class MD5IntegrityCheck
{
  public static void main(String[] args)

  {

            String fileName,Md5checksum ,sql;

            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement pst;
            Statement stmt;
            ResultSet rs;

                    try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con1 =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RecordTbl","scott","tiger");
                    }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {ee.printStackTrace( );}




            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    }

                    /****insert method******/






        private static void setDefaultCloseOperation(String exitOnClose) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

                    static void setVisible(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    try{


                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RecordTbl","scott","tiger");
                        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into RecordTbl values(?,?)");
                String fileName = null;
                pst.setString(1,fileName);
                String Md5checksum = null;
                pst.setString(2,Md5checksum);

                int i=pst.executeUpdate( );

                System.out.println("recorded in database");
                con.close( );
                        }
                catch(Exception ee)
                {ee.printStackTrace( );}
                    }



                }   

    if (args.length <= 0)
    {
      Md5Gui gui = new Md5Gui();
      gui.runGui();
    }
    else
    {
      DoWork runningProgram = new DoWork();
      runningProgram.run(args);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you provided oracle drivers in class path

Comment: Have you got the MySQL JDBC library in your lib folder / class path.

Comment: possibilty duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2591505/668970

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague:

In your exception, you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` for a driver that pertains to MySQL. On your code, you're using a JDBC-ODBC Driver.

My suggestion is how did you configure your database connectivity. Let's start from there. Also, it would be better to add the exception stack trace to see exactly what's happening.

**Edit**: Visit [this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0112.html) if you want to know how to configure JDBC connection to Oracle Database. I fully **recommend** using the Oracle JDBC driver directly instead of connecting it to an ODBC Bridge.

Comment: that is not for mysql, its oracle drivers

Comment: @Damodar, the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` pertains to the MySQL RDBMS and not Oracle Driver.

Comment: but he is implementing for oracle driver in his code  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");             Connection con1 =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RecordTbl","scott","tiger");. Also he mentioned tag as oracle

Comment: @Damodar, yes he did...but the OP never used Oracle Driver in any instance. `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` is not an Oracle DB driver and neither is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (which is MySQL Driver). The OP should use the correct driver. His/Her code is wrong when connecting with JDBC. That's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman : cannt we connect oracle with jdbcodbc drivers? also , username and password ,mentioned there is default cerdentials of oracle database

Comment: @Damodar, the ODBC driver exists. If you're persistent enough, you can set it up but I would **recommend** using the JDBC driver directly.

Comment: @user762357, I can't edit your code **until** you specify how you have configured your oracle connections and `tnsnames.ora`. Follow the example I've provided.

Comment: No problems. Hope this helps and don't forget to accept correct answers (by ticking the checkbox under the score) :)

Comment: can u see thhis by team viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might be running your program in IDE, so please add drivers jars in the classpath of project

Comment: what Class path path ..Please tell

Comment: whats the database you are using with version numer

Answer (score 0):

You should look into any 3rd party library you're using whether there a MySQL database driver is needed. Although you write you are using an Oracle driver (though the `JdbcOdbcDriver` is provided by Java itself and has nothing to do with Oracle DB's) the exception is clearly stating that the MySQL is requested. Since you don't use it in the code you provided, there must be another database connection using MySQL.