# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver When run jar file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Hi all,
here is my sample code:

```
Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "test";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "root"; 
String password = "admin";
try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
  System.out.println("Connected to the database");
  conn.close();
  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I run in eclipse it's ok, but i built to jar file and run on command line `java -jar Test.jar` i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me how to fix it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the MySQL JDBC driver `.jar` file, or it is not in your classpath.

Comment: I all set the classpath =  C:\Users\My\Downloads\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar and add in project buildpath, but it still error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put sql driver into the class path, place the driver in the same folder as your jar file and run

java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar -jar Test.jar

you can download mysql java driver from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I tried, but it still error. Are there any problem?

Comment: the class.forName bit looked odd to me, try this instead Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Answer (score 1):

in case if you are using maven, add following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.13</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still not work ^_^.

Comment: are you using maven dependency ?

Comment: no, i don't use maven. Can you tell me which packet content this driver String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add MySQL jdbc driver jar file in to your classpath.

Comment: It also exist in my classpath <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar"/>, but still error.