# database connectivity - java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I have an exception here in the following code... I am trying to build a simple servlet project and I have the following exception raised: `java.net.UnknownHostException`...
I have the mysql jar file added and besides...I have added it as an external jar file and also under lib in WEB-INF, as stated in [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/540648/JDBC/databases/java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-mysql-jdbc), but now this is throwing an `java.net.UnknownHostException`.

This is the code and the exception stack trace.

```
package com.servlet.Mysql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Connection_Class {
String driver_ClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String URL_connection="jdbc:mysql://localhost3306/vendor";
String user="root";
String password="lifesuckzz";
private static Connection_Class connectionclass=null;

private Connection_Class(){
    try{
        Class.forName(driver_ClassName);

    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    Connection con=null;
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL_connection,user,password);
    return con;
}

public static Connection_Class getInstance(){
    if(connectionclass==null){
        connectionclass=new Connection_Class();
    }
    return connectionclass;}}
```

Stack trace:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.UnknownHostException
MESSAGE: localhost3306

STACKTRACE:

java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost3306
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:133)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:280)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1699)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:405)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.servlet.Mysql.Connection_Class.getConnection(Connection_Class.java:25)
at com.servlet.Mysql.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1764)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:405)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.servlet.Mysql.Connection_Class.getConnection(Connection_Class.java:25)
at com.servlet.Mysql.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using Apache Web container and Eclipse, this post [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in spite of using CLASSPATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver) I think wasnt near to my case here.....please help me out, thank you all in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed the colon between hostname and port number... Your connection URL should be

```
String URL_connection="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendor";
```

Comment: Some times it happens buddy... We are all same.... You can upvote the answer if it helped you..

Answer (score 3):

I think the connection URL should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendor` . `localhost` is the server name and `3306` the port name separated by `:`.

```
String URL_connection="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendor";
```

Please go through the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

*The JDBC URL format for MySQL Connector/J is as follows, with items in square brackets ([, ]) being optional:*

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
```

*If the host name is not specified, it defaults to 127.0.0.1. If the port is not specified, it defaults to 3306*.