# mysql and java connection

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I'm trying to connect java with a mysql database but I am getting a null pointer exception.

Note: I used this method before and it worked well

this is the code :

```
    public void OpenConnection () throws SQLException{
   try {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            try {
       con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hema?"
          + "user=root&password=hima27890");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.print("Connection Not Found");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.print("Not found Class");
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.close();
    }




}
```

and this is the method to return some data in database :

```
     public String[] GetData(String website) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
//        System.out.println("\nGet data method");
//        System.out.println("connection will start now");
       OpenConnection();
         System.out.println("connection works");

        String queryget="SELECT * FROM hema.passwords WHERE website='"+website+"'";

        Statement stm=(Statement) con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stm.executeQuery(queryget);

        if(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("if works");
             arr[0]=rs.getString("email");
        arr[1]=rs.getString("username");
        arr[2]=rs.getString("password");

        }
        else{

        System.out.println("The website doesn't exist");
        }
        System.out.println("method done");
        return arr;
    }



}
```

**I put some System.out.print to know where is the error and all of them forked but not tje last one "method done".**

and this is the code in the JForm that call the last method :

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        String Website = jTextField1.getText();
        System.out.println("Website is "+Website);
        Model model=new Model();
        String arr2[]=model.GetData(Website);
        System.out.println("App");
        EmailText.setText(arr2[0]);
        UserText.setText(arr2[1]);
        PasswordText.setText(arr2[2]);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Passwords.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Passwords.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }





}
```

the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Model.Model.GetData(Model.java:68)
at View.Passwords.jButton1ActionPerformed(Passwords.java:161)
at View.Passwords.access$200(Passwords.java:15)
at View.Passwords$3.actionPerformed(Passwords.java:64)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 21 seconds)

Comment: Note: I used this method before and it worked well

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: have u added mysql jar to ur project?

Comment: yes sure I've done that

Comment: Where is the rest of your code. Your stack trace shows an error in an action handler and not that block of code

Comment: the rest of the code was added

Answer (score 0):

ok I knew where is the problem
it was in declaring `array` of strings in the beginning of the code so it didn't change when i used the if statement so I used array `ArrayList<String>`