# Hadoop does not load jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, jdbc

I am writing a program in Hadoop, which uses MySql to read data from dfs. I get this message upon run:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ConnectDtb.<init>(ConnectDtb.java:14)
    at WriteToDtb.<init>(WriteToDtb.java:14)
    at WriteToDtb.main(WriteToDtb.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

When I run it without Hadoop, I'm not getting this error.

I have put `mysql-connector.jar` to `$Hadoop/lib`, tried to run with `-libjars <mysql-connector path>` but it fails as well.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying

> mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar

to

> /var/lib/hadoop

It works for me. The startup script will tell the classpath to look here for the connector jar for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1.** Add this line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_LIB=$HADOOP/lib
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_LIB/mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx.jar
```

**METHOD 2.** Add this line in `/home/hadoop/.bashrc`: (Here **hadoop** is my hadoop username)

```
export HADOOP_LIB=$HADOOP/lib
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_LIB/mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx.jar
```

> **NOTE:** Change **mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx.jar** to your MySQL connector jar file version.