# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver if the project built into jar

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I made my project use NetBeans, when I run it through NetBeans, it can run properly without any errors at all.
But, when I build it into a jar file and try to login to  my application, I get an error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

[image: error1]

And in cmd :

[image: error]

I have been do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762254/4369288) tutorial and it not work.
And I have been read and follow tutorial that was similar with this my problem in this website and others website, but nothing work for me.

this is my library :
[image: my library]

And this is my code

```
 package config;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author nasution
 */
public class Koneksi {
    private static Connection koneksi;
    public static Statement stm;

    public static Connection getKoneksi() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_surat","root","");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "koneksi gagal"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        return koneksi;
    }

}
```

this is my project that has been converted to jar :
[image: project jar]

and this is my library in folder "dist/lib" that was generated when I built the project
[image: my library]

Comment: You can package all the dependencies with your jar or set the lib path

Comment: do you mean, set in classpath ?

Comment: thanks, it's has been solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare required libraries in the [`/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). If you look at [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) the syntax will be:

```
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
```

How will you modify the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` depends on your JAR packaging mechanism, most of them give you an option to auto-generate this file.